# To monitor and watch a non browser application web operation

Tags: webserver, url

How do we monitor, watch and inspect a non browser application, eg. a Telegram channel, downloading operation processes in order to find the original/sourced media file URL ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tcpflow](https://github.com/simsong/tcpflow). It can do more than just log which processes are accessing which URLs (which is just port 443 and port 80), but other ports aswell. It also has a powerful filterig ability.

See this [tutorial](https://www.tecmint.com/tcpflow-analyze-debug-network-traffic-in-linux/) on how to use it.